# Why is the file name being changed?

Tags: python, automation, save, wget, wallpaper

I created an automated script in Python to change my wallpaper on my desktop using the unsplash.com API. It runs fine, except when I tell it to save the file as `wallpaper.jpg` it does that once, then every file saved thereafter is saved as `wallpaper(1).jpg`. Why is this happening? I want the file to be saved simply as `wallpaper.jpg`.

I worked around the problem in the change_wallpaper function so that it retrieves the `wallpaper(1).jpg` file, but I would rather not have to do this if possible.

```py
# import dependencies
import os
import requests
import wget
import ctypes
import time

from config import UNSPLASH_ACCESS_KEY


def get_wallpaper():
    # create API query and define parameters
    url = 'https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random?client_id=' + UNSPLASH_ACCESS_KEY
    params = {
        "query": "HD Wallpapers",
        "orientation": "landscape"
    }
    # create request, define json format, grab image url, and save to folder
    response = requests.get(url, params=params).json()
    image_url = response['urls']['full']
    # download the image
    image = wget.download(image_url, 'tmp/wallpaper.jpg')
    return image


def change_wallpaper():
    get_wallpaper()
    # create path using cwd, current working directory, and use ctypes to update the designated image as the wallpaper.
    path = os.getcwd()+'\\tmp\\wallpaper (1).jpg'
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20,0, path,3)

def main():

    try:
        while True:
            change_wallpaper()
            time.sleep(10)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nThank you, come again!")
    except Exception as e:
        pass

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The `wallpaper(1).jpg` type of filename sounds like something is using some sort of file copy from the windows operating system which will rename the new file so that it doesn't overwrite any existing file. Are you able to delete the original file first?

Comment: Yes, so even when I delete both files (wallpaper.jpg and wallpaper(1).jpg) and run the script, it creates a wallpaper.jpg file, then a wallpaper(1).jpg file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `wget` module doesn't have the capability to overwrite existing files you will need to delete the existing file before you try to download a new one. You can do this within your code as follows.

```
import os

if os.path.exists(filename):
    os.remove(filename)
```

Comment: That worked! I put the conditional statement at the beginning of the get_wallpaper function so that it is called every time the program is run. 

```
def get_wallpaper():
    if os.path.exists('tmp/wallpaper.jpg'):
        os.remove('tmp/wallpaper.jpg')
   ...........
```
Thank you!